# neutralize score on field

Tags: .net, lucene, lucene.net

is it possible to create a searchQuery where all results gets the same score ?
example: 
I have some document types i'd like to search in, and i'd like the match on the document types to not have any effect on the score.

(nodeTypeAlias: newsItem nodeTypeAlias: activity)
this Query give me all the items which has newsItem or activity as nodeTypeAlias, but the problem is that activity Items has a score of 2,7581 and newsItem items has a score of 0,1061. Which gives the activity items a headstart, and that is not wanted.

Ived tried to boost with 0, using lucene.net, but when passed to the QueryParser it converts it to ^.0, and lucene breaks on such query.

So question is: How can i get a field search to not effect the score, but other fields should (these fields i actually search in with the searchQuery).

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the query, or subquery, in a [`ConstantScoreQuery`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_8_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/ConstantScoreQuery.html), like:

```
Query constantQuery = new ConstantScoreQuery(nodeTypeAliasBQ);
booleanQuery.add(new BooleanClause(constantQuery, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST));
booleanQuery.add(new BooleanClause(someOtherQuery, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD));
```

---

Prior to 3.1, `ConstantScoreQuery` can only be used with a `Filter`, rather than a `Query`.  You can do this a couple of ways.

1. Wrap the query in a [`QueryWrapperFilter`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/api/all/org/apache/lucene/search/QueryWrapperFilter.html):

   ```
   Query constantQuery = new ConstantScoreQuery(new QueryWrapperFilter(nodeTypeBQ))
   ```

   Fun fact: There is still code to support/optimize this pattern, noted in source with:

   > Fix outdated usage pattern from Lucene 2.x/early-3.x: because ConstantScoreQuery only accepted filters, QueryWrapperFilter was used to wrap queries.
2. Use a [`TermsFilter`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/api/all/org/apache/lucene/search/TermsFilter.html):

   ```
   Filter nodeTypeFilter = new TermsFilter();
   nodeTypeFilter.addTerm(new Term("nodeTypeAlias","newsItem"));
   nodeTypeFilter.addTerm(new Term("nodeTypeAlias","activity"));
   Query constantQuery = new ConstantScoreQuery(nodeTypeFilter)
   ```

Comment: Seems like what im looking for. Though, im on 2.9.4 lucene.net, and when im using ConstantScoreQuery i can only give it a filter, which i can't figure out. any pointers ?

Comment: when i excute this query ConstantScore(QueryWrapperFilter(nodeTypeAlias:activity nodeTypeAlias:workgroup)) in luke i get two different scores on the NodeTypeAlias. 
Im building in Umbraco, so im using a framework to work with Lucene, but as far as i know, i should be able to to the same things as a queryString as using the API, but the result isn't as expected. Any ideers?